# Remote Access a PhoneGap App

Tags: ios, cordova, embeddedwebserver

I wanted to make an application for the iPad that will be controlled from an iPhone-app. Is there a possibility to access the PhoneGap-App on the iPhone?
I don't want to use an external server because the app should run offline in an Ad-Hoc network.

First I thought of creating a local webserver on the iPad, but I couldn't find anything PhoneGap related. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were probably on the right track with the web server idea.

I am not sure how well the various solutions are supported in PhoneGap, but I would think you could use some sort of WebSockets implementation for the bi-directional communication between the iPhone and iPad apps.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. I had no Idea where to start – thanks!